# Precisely timed Custom Vibrations

Tags: iphone, ios, hardware, vibrate

Is there a way create a precisely timed Custom Vibration in iOS 13 or later?

Additionally, is it possible to make the vibration short enough to mimic the 3D Touch haptic feedback on devices with the Taptic Engine? Do Custom Vibrations even use the Taptic Engine APIs and subsequently is it even capable of that type of vibration?

Essentially I’m trying to mimic the “Synchronized” vibration style with my own custom Alert Tone. I’m pretty much willing to go as far as building a little Arduino motor if that’s really what it takes, but I would like to know if anyone else knows any solutions that don’t require me replacing my human finger with a well-timed machine finger, because I haven’t found any.